# Neo4J / Cypher - Calculate durations between 2 without weekend days

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way with neo4j / cypher to calculate the difference in days between two dates without including weekends (basically only counting worked/company open days) ?

Something in the line of this query :

```
return duration.inDays(date("2022-01-01"), date("2022-01-19")).days
```

But without the weekend days.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: You should define what a week-end is. This varies from country to country.

Comment: Well I'm more interested in having something adaptable, but for the sake of the example Saturday and Sunday works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no date function for working days but we can compute it by creating a list of dates between start date and end date. Then using the function weekDay where weekday:1 is monday and 5 is friday, we can remove the weekends from the list. Then count the number for working days in that list.

```
   WITH date("2022-01-01") AS startDate, date("2022-10-19") AS endDate
   WITH startDate, duration.inDays(startDate, endDate).days AS days
   WITH [day in range(0, days) | startDate + duration({days: day})] as calendarDays
   WITH [c in calendarDays where c.weekDay < 6 | c] as workingDays
   RETURN size(workingDays) as workingDays


╒═════════════╕
│"workingDays"│
╞═════════════╡
│208          │
└─────────────┘
```

Comment: this is a nice query !

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you if there is a way to wrap this into a "user defined procedure" (not sure that's the right term but basically being able to wrap this and make it reusable)

Comment: You are totally correct. We can submit an enhancement request to Neo4j to create an APOC function about it. Thanks.

Comment: Here is APOC docu site: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12955.   Submitted a feature request to Neo4j.

Comment: Oh really cool, thanks for pushing this ticket !

Comment: Thanks to you! You come up with that idea.  Good1 Overdrivr!